# arrow key behaves abnormally on linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I connect to the remote Linux (desktop version) via ssh on my laptop. When the firefox with GUI (or other softwares) is opened, the arrow keys are out of work. Specifically, when the up arrow is pressed, the effect is equal to '8' is pressed and held.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved via switching the input method from chinese to english.